# Text makes td with fixed width bigger

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a td with a fixed width and a background image. When there's text in the td that's longer than that width, it doesn't go on a new line, it expands my td. Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: It does wrap around for me. Could you post html + css code?

Comment: Which browser are you testing with?

Answer (score 4):

the exemple
http://jsfiddle.net/pqVYj/1/

you can use CSS3 property `word-wrap: break-word;.`

more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Word-wrap

code exemple in case links won't work:

```
p { width:13em; background:gold; word-wrap:break-word; }​
```

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of a tweak, but you can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/A3xs7/

Look a the third `tr`

Just include a `div` and set the dimension that you want and add `overlow:hidden;` to the `div`.

Comment: your solution just hides the content if it's bigger then the width of div, but he needs it to go on a new line

here is your example with more text:  http://jsfiddle.net/A3xs7/1/
so this is no good for this issue. P.S. It's not me with the down vote here :)

Comment: ooh fail, i read it all wrong, i've read it like this "when it go on a new line the td grow", well my bad